# Handler function invoking many times in setInterval of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a setInterval function that accepts user input every 15 seconds.
All works great, but I believe each invocation of the handler success script is executed n times (where n is the number of times the script has prompted the dialog since the start).

After I load the web page, after 15 sec, it prompts a message and asks for input, I type as "**first**" and the success handler is executed once displays in the console.

At 30th second, the script asks me again and I type "second", now the script is executed two times instead of once for the second slot. The listener of first is also executed along with second causing the output as

[image]

How do I make the success handler function only once for each run of setInterval?

My code is below

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Alert-Confirm-Prompt-Dialog-Plugin-jQuery/css/really-simple-jquery-dialog.css">
    <style>
    body { font-family:'Roboto'; text-align:center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
wait 15 seconds to get prompt and type something and click accept 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="testPrompt"></div>
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Alert-Confirm-Prompt-Dialog-Plugin-jQuery/js/really-simple-jquery-dialog.js"></script-->


<script type="text/javascript">

(function($) {
    $.fn.simplePrompt = function(options) {
        if (typeof options === 'undefined') options = {};

        var defaultOptions = {
            title: 'Prompt',
            message: '',
            acceptBtnLabel: 'Accept',
            cancelBtnLabel: 'Cancel',
            success: function(result) {},
            cancel: function(result) {}
        }
        options = $.extend(defaultOptions, options);

        this.each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var html;

            $this.addClass('simple-dialog active');

            html = '<div class="simple-dialog-content">';
            html += '<div class="simple-dialog-header"><h3 class="title">'+options.title+'</h3></div>';
            html += '<div class="simple-dialog-body"><p class="message">'+options.message+'</p><p class="answer"><input type="text" /></p></div>';
            html += '<div class="simple-dialog-footer clearfix"><a class="simple-dialog-button accept" data-action="close">'+options.acceptBtnLabel+'</a><a class="simple-dialog-button cancel" data-action="close">'+options.cancelBtnLabel+'</a></div>';
            html += '</div>';

            $this.html(html);

            $(document).on('click', 'a[data-action="close"]', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var result = $('.answer input').val();
                $(this).parents('.simple-dialog').removeClass('active');
                if($(this).hasClass('accept')) {
                    options.success(result);
                }
                if($(this).hasClass('cancel')) {
                    options.cancel(result);
                }
            });
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#testPrompt').simplePrompt({
            message: "Hello World!!",
            success: function(result) {
                console.log("Success" + result)
            },
            cancel: function(result) {
                console.log("Cancel")
            }
        });
    }, 15000);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` is actually registering a click handler every 15 seconds.

What you need to do is `unbind` or turn `off` the click handler `$(document).off('click', 'a[data-action="close"]')` on the success and cancel callbacks.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
          $('#testPrompt').simplePrompt({
            message: "Hello World!!",
            success: function(result) {
              console.log("Success" + result)
               $(document).off('click', 'a[data-action="close"]');
            },
            cancel: function(result) {
              console.log("Cancel")
              $(document).off('click', 'a[data-action="close"]');
            }
          });
        }, 15000);
      });
```

But I think a better solution is to check whether the prompt is visible. If the prompt is visible you do not want to call `simplePrompt` function.

So,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      var promptVisible = false;
        setInterval(function() {
        if(!promptVisible){
              $('#testPrompt').simplePrompt({
            message: "Hello World!!",
            success: function(result) {
              console.log("Success" + result)
               $(document).off('click', 'a[data-action="close"]');
               promptVisible = false;
            },
            cancel: function(result) {
              console.log("Cancel")
              $(document).off('click', 'a[data-action="close"]');
              promptVisible = false;
            }
          });
          promptVisible = true;
        }
        
        }, 15000);
      });
```

Link to [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pa9e63f2/5/)